# Convergence in probability of uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Define in some probability space the random variables $X_2,X_3,\ldots$, where each $X_n$ r.v. is uniformly distributed in the $n-$th unitary sphere
$$ B_n(0,1)=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \vert \vert x \vert \vert ^2 \leq 1\}$$
where $\vert \vert x \vert \vert$ is the $\mathbb{R}^n$ Euclidean norm. By definition of uniform distribution, is $A$ is a measurable subset of $B_n(0,1)$ then $\mathbb{P}(X_n \in A) = \operatorname{vol}(A)/\operatorname{vol}(B(0,1))$, where $\operatorname{vol}$ is the $n-$dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Let $R_n=\vert \vert X_n \vert \vert$. Show that $R_n \to 1$ in probability when $n \to \infty$.

This is how I have tried to understand this problem:

1. As you sample your variables you are increasing the dimension of the sphere and the previous samples belong to a subset $A$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$ in $B_n(0,1)$ since $A$ will have at least one ''flat'' component.
2. To prove that $R_n \to 1$ in probability is equivalent as to show that with probability $1$ you will find the $X_n$ r.v. in the surface of the $n-$sphere. (or for every $\epsilon>0$, close enough to the surface of the sphere)

2.1) This is where it gets confusing, as if the samples are uniformly distributed in $B_n(0,1)$ it makes no sense to me to prove that the r.v should fall on the surface. In particular, for every $\epsilon>0$ you can define the subset $A_{\epsilon}$ as the ball $B_n(0, 1-\epsilon)$ and then $\mathbb{P}(X_n \in A_\epsilon) \neq 0$.

3. Besides changing the dimension of the unit ball, I don't see how $n\to \infty$ affects the outcome of the r.v. $X_n$.

Any guidance is highly appreciated. Maybe (possibly) I am not understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: Do you know the *precise* definition of convergence in measure? What can you say about the measure of $\{x \in \Bbb{R}^n : \|x\|\leq 1-\epsilon\}$ compared to the measure of the unit ball?

Comment: What I understand for convergence in measure is that if $X_n\to b$, then for every $\epsilon >0$, $Lim_{n\to \infty} P(\vert X_n - b \vert < \epsilon)=1$. And, as it is said in the problem, the measure of $B_n(0,1-\epsilon)$ should be its volume, which is strictly less than the one of the unit ball, but not $0$ as long as $1>\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}P(|R_n - 1| < \epsilon)
&= P(|\|X_n\| - 1| < \epsilon)
\\
&= P( 1 - \epsilon < \|X_n\| < 1+\epsilon)
\\
&= P(\|X_n\| > 1-\epsilon)
\\
&=  1 - \frac{\text{Vol}(B_n(0, 1-\epsilon))}{\text{Vol}(B_n(0, 1)}.
\end{align}$$

Can you show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{Vol}(B_n(0, 1-\epsilon))}{\text{Vol}(B_n(0, 1)} = 0$?

Comment: That was exactly my point... in this case, that could be $0$ for $\epsilon \to 0$ but it has nothing to do with $n\to \infty$. Is that enough to show that the statement is false?

Comment: @leplata: What is the measure of $[-2,2]^2$? What is the measure of $[-2,2]^3$? What of $[-2,2]^4$? Now think again about the volume of the ball with radius $1-\epsilon$ in dimension $n$.

Comment: I found that by Stirling's formula one can say that $\text{vol}(B_n(R)) \approx 1/\sqrt{n \pi }\left(2\pi e/n\right)^{n/2} R^n=C_n R^n$. In this case, we would have the $R_1=1-\epsilon$ and $R_2=1$ and so, when doing $\text{vol}B_n(1-\epsilon)/\text{vol}B_n(1)$ the $C_n$ cancel out and we get $((1-\epsilon)/1)^n$ which goes to $0$ for $n\to \infty$.  Is there a more intuitive way of showing this?

Comment: @leplata Your argument here is fine; the key point is that the volume is proportional to $R^n$.